# Chartjs 3.x Migration Guide notes on animation not working

Tags: typescript, chart.js

as I was working on updating the code for my charts created with `Chartjs`, I was using the migration guide:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Most of the stuff written works, but I seem to have issues with some of the points written under **Specific changes**, to be precise it's these two:

`responsiveAnimationDuration` is now configured in `animation.resize.duration`

`hover.animationDuration` is now configured in `animation.active.duration`

So this is the structure I have in my code:

```
new Chart(
    // ...
    options: {
        // ...
        animation: {
            resize: {        // IDE already complaining here that 'resize' does not exist
                duration: 0,
            },
            active: {        // Same problem here
                duration: 0,
            },
        },
    },
```

**I'm using version 3.5.1, if that's of any help**

Is there anything I'm missing or am I doing something wrong?
Did anyone else encounter this issue?

Comment: are you trying to disable animations?

Comment: that's the main goal, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just set `animation` to `false`:

```
options: { 
    animation: false,
    ...
```

You can read more at [Disabling animation.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#disabling-animation)

Comment: Thank you, I guess this works as well.
Wondering though why I can't do it the way it's being written in the guide. If I just wanted to disable the animation for resizing for example, I would still have this issue.

Comment: Nevermind, I've just read the link you've posted, that answers it ^^